# How to evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[3]{x^5}(\sqrt[3]{x+1}+\sqrt[3]{x-1}-2\sqrt[3]x)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I know that I can use L'Hôpital's rule to evaluate$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt[3]{x^5}(\sqrt[3]{x+1}+\sqrt[3]{x-1}-2\sqrt[3]{x})$$but I am unsure how to.

I've been struggling on this one for like the whole day and I would love to see some other ideas. So far I have factored the $\sqrt[3]{x^5}$ to each term (which an answer told me to do), but it didn't help.

I also tried to change it to an $\frac\infty\infty$ form and to use L'Hôpital's rule and that seems to give the closest answer so far, but I seem to have done something wrong.

I also have tried the sum of cubes formula and it didn't work either after I separated the limits. I really don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y:=\dfrac1x$, so
$$\begin{aligned}
L =\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt[3]{x^6+x^5}+\sqrt[3]{x^6-x^5}-2x^2
&= \lim_{x\to\infty} x^2\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac1x}+\sqrt[3]{1-\frac1x}-2\right)\\
&= \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+y}+\sqrt[3]{1-y}-2}{y^2}
\end{aligned}$$
Both the numerator and the denominator goes to zero, therefore, by L'Hopital's rule
$$L = \lim_{y\to0} \frac{\frac13(1+y)^{-2/3}-\frac13(1-y)^{-2/3}}{2y} = \frac16\lim_{y\to0}\frac{(1+y)^{-2/3}-(1-y)^{-2/3}}{y}$$
Again the numerator and the denominator goes to zero, so we can apply L'Hopital's rule one last time to conclude
$$L = \frac16\lim_{y\to0}-\frac23(1+y)^{-5/3}-\frac23(1-y)^{-5/3} = \frac16\cdot \left(-\frac43\right) = -\frac29.$$